# Boat in Narrowing Canal Force

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram

[image: boat through a canal funnel]

I have the following scenario. An object (blue) is going straight at 5m/s and is 100 kg.
The object hits a frictionless wall that is at a 10 degree angle and continues in the same direction (is funneled). What is the force applied to the wall from the object? The point of contact would be a single point and not a face/plane.

The real world scenario would be a boat in a river that is being funneled towards a thinner canal.

I thought of the problem by finding the kinetic energy of the object and then dividing by distance. However, in this scenario, the object would continue to move, so I'm unsure of what the "distance" is since the object doesn't stop. Additionally, I thought of the distance as the compression of the object or wall (like if it was a tire) and that the distance could be compression of the tire. Finally, I thought possibly the distance would be the distance from the horizontal distance from the impact to until it is at the straight portion where it is no longer in contact with the wall.

Thank you in advance for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information to answer the question.

To get the force you would need to know how the wall and boat deform. Otherwise you've got an instantaneous "bounce" kind of thing. The force is huge for a very short time. Even minor deformation will change the force by a large amount. So you need to know something like the elastic nature of the wall and boat, or the inelastic crumpling, or something of that general nature. You will also need a more accurate model than just a sphere with a point contact.

To get something of what a real boat would do, you would also need to know something about the amount of water it was dragging, how the water was flowing, and so on. But that's getting mighty complicated.  For example, when the boat hits the wall and changes velocity, the water it was dragging then tries to push it along.